# What kind of compression does Gradle Jar task use?

Tags: gradle, jar

I have a fairly strait forward gradle 2.13 project (some Java 8, Scala 2.10, and binary resources). Anyway I've noticed the difference between a compressed jar and uncompressed is only around 11%.

I proved that it isn't just data that doesn't compress well by trying to compress the same thing via command line jar tool and achieve 56% compression. So any idea what algorithm it's using that doesn't seem to be performing particularly well?

*uncompressed jar is 18MB

Comment: This is a question for programmers.stackexchange.com. SO is best suited to ask details and get downvoted.